# NotesDatabase search with more than 1 parameter

Tags: javascript, xpages

I'm trying to get the documents which match my codes criteria:

```
var allrelevant:NotesDocumentCollection = db.search("Sender='sender'" + "To='addressee'");
```

db is a NotesDatabase that I have defined earlier in the code. The `.search()` works okay with 1 string (for example "Sender='sender'") but I can't figure out how to search database with 2 conditions (2 strings). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search- string is an @Formula- Syntax as you would use it in a view selection formula and can contain all elements that are allowed in that context.

If @Formula there are the logical operators:

```
& - and  
| - Or  
! - not
```

Your search for multiple fields would then be:

```
Sender='sender' & To='addressee'
```

or in your example

```
"Sender='sender'" + "&" + "To='addressee'"
```

Comment: Figured this out minute after posting the question, but thanks for the answer! I found an article where the same functionality was achieved by using session scope variables and putting them in the search condition. Is that in any way better than just putting raw string value in the search?

Comment: It depends on your use case: If you need your search string later, then putting it in a sessionScope is a good thing to do, if it is "one shot search" then a simple string is totally sufficient

Comment: 1) you can use all `@Formulas`, e.g. `@Matches`, `@Contains`... 2) I doubt apostrophe is valid in search formula 3) you can make managed bean, whose properties would be binded to search values with method getFormula() returning exact search formula based on binded values.